# Getting WinError 267 when trying to install BMTK on Anaconda environment

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I am having trouble installing brain modelling toolkit, BMTK, in an Anaconda environment I named BMTK1.

As you can see from the code I'm getting an error "WinError 267"

What's going on here?

I tired to go to the folder "aux" but its not there. I tried changing the name of site-packages to remove the hyphen but that did nothing. What am I missing?

I have admin access on this computer, but it is a workplace machine.

```
    (BMTK1) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c kaeldai bmtk
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\BMTK1

  added / updated specs:
    - bmtk


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  bmtk               kaeldai/win-64::bmtk-0.0.6-py36_0
  libiconv           pkgs/main/win-64::libiconv-1.15-h1df5818_7
  libxml2            pkgs/main/win-64::libxml2-2.9.12-h0ad7f3c_0
  libxslt            pkgs/main/win-64::libxslt-1.1.34-he774522_0
  lxml               pkgs/main/win-64::lxml-4.6.3-py36h9b66d53_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  openssl                                 1.1.1l-h2bbff1b_0 --> 1.1.1m-h2bbff1b_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'kaeldai::bmtk-0.0.6-py36_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\BMTK1\\Lib\\site-packages\\bmtk\\builder\\aux'
()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WinError+267